# Should the word determines in this sentence be singular? And does the entire sentence make sense syntactically?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> This negative attitude reflects your thoughts which *determines* your success or failure.

I'm an amateur editor, I'm looking to improve myself drastically. This is one sentence in a copy that I was editing that has persistently stuck with me for quite some time now. For one thing, I tagged the determines as a pluralization error and changed it to "determine" did I make the right call here? Are there other issues in this particular sentence that I should have taken note of?

Can anyone point out the parts of the sentence in this instance as well? For reference.

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples on a dictionary or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not. Here are some online free references that are commonly recognized,Wikipedia, Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, VOA, Google Ngram.

Answer (score 2):

As 'thoughts' are plural, so subject-verb agreement tells us the correct form of the verb is determine. Yes, you made the right call.

Note, 'which' (relative pronoun) represents 'your thoughts' in the sentence.

This negative attitude reflects your **thoughts** which determine your success or failure.